# Im trying to use prepared statements with a search bar php

Tags: php, html, search

I have a search function on a page, but I need to use prepared statements. It keeps sending back 0 results when trying to use it.

Here is the page where the search bar is.

```
<form action="search.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Value To Search">
    <button type="submit" name="search">
    </button>
</form>
```

this is the search.php page

```
<?php

$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '1234', 'users');

if (isset($_POST['search'])) {

    $search = $_POST['search'];    

    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $search);
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

        echo "<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>id</th></tr>";

        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<tr><td>" . $row["username"] . "</td><td>" . $row["id"] . "</td></tr>";
        }

        echo "</table>";

    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: could you please add your table structure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both your button and your input has the name "search", therefore, your $_POST['search'] does not contain a relevant value. More specifically, it will always be the empty string `""` as it will take the value of the last field with this name (e.g the button).

Try changing the name of the input, or the name of the submit button.